# Delete data using on CASCADE DELETE but delete the records from the child tables in batches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have just tried using delete statement but it will delete all the records of the child tables at once. but I have to delete them in batches

Suppose I have a parent table with user information like userid, username, age etc.. and in the child table there are million messages for a particular user, how I can delete the messages from the second table in batches using on cascade delete?

Comment: You write yourself a stored procedure which deleted them in the batch size you desire. There is no automatic way to do it.

Comment: If you make the foreign key column nullable, you can use `ON DELETE SET NULL` and then have an independent process later go through and batch-delete child records having a null parent ID. This would still trigger an immediate update of all child records, but this might be faster than the cascade delete.

Comment: Another option is to define but then disable your foreign key relationship. This would allow the parent row to be deleted while the child rows remain. A background process could then check for and delete orphaned rows. Adding an `AFTER DELETE` trigger that records deleted parent IDs in a post-processing queue (table of deleted IDs)could make the post-processing more efficient than potential full-table scans. This will prevent enforcement of referential integrity on that FK, so any queries against the child tables would need to accommodate the possibility of a missing parent.